# Magento 2 not loading catalog pages

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 not showing Blocks, Pages, Product pages. They show Pre-loader only.

They show error on console:

[image: error on console]

> Error: Script error for: rjsResolver
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Please help me.